# A counting problem potentially using lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've been working on some problems within combinatorics, and I ran into a
problem that may use lattice paths in the answer, but I am not entirely sure how
to go about it.

Given $n$, I want to count the number of sequences of $n$ integers $b_1,...,b_n$
such that $1 \leq b_1 \leq b_2 \leq ... \leq b_n, b_i \leq i.$ It is apparent
that this is to some extent a lattice path problem with the height of a
given column dictated by $b_i \leq i$. However, I am having some problems how
exactly I constrain the up-down structure of the lattice paths to this
particular problem. Should I potentially do an unconstrained $n \times n$
board, and then perform inclusion-exclusion to remove ways that do not
satisfy our constraints? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds very much like the Catalan numbers. I don't know if that's a good starting point if you want to solve this yourself, but it isn't the easiest thing to derive a closed form from staring at the lattice paths.